# Magento2 : limit concurrent logins for the same customer account

Tags: magento-2.1.7, customer-session

I want to limit concurrent logins for the same customer account. If customer already logged in one device and also try to login from another device then customer should be logout from previous session. Similar the Admin login sharing feature in magento2.

I want to implement this feature for customer session as well.